# What's the best way to update sister sub-feature branch taken from feature branch if one of them is merged to master?

Tags: git, merge

Given `master -> A`, `A->B1`, and `A->B2`.

If `B2` is merged into master, what's the best way to update `B1`?

I am trying to understand the best practice in terms of merging a hierarchy of branches.

What is acceptable and what is not (i.e. what may lead to merging conflicts or messed up GitHub files changed tab)

when does it make sense to merge back in order and when does it make sense to merge directly whether it be feature branches backwards towards master or master towards feature branches or between offshoots of feature branches?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but I think you're asking about this situation:

```
B1                ,-o--o--o
                 /
A             ,-o--o
             /      \         
B2          /        '-o--o
           /               \
master  --o--o--o-----------o--
```

Where A is branched off of master, B1 and B2 are branched off of A.

I don't think there's anything that can be described as best practice for a problem described in abstract terms like this, it very much depends on what the *purposes* of all the branches involved are.

If branch A represents work for a feature, is intended to have other commits and be merged back to master at some point, then I would question why B2 was merged into master rather than back into A.

If A does not represent work on a particular feature, but B1 and B2 do, then I think B1 can just be merged into master.

If the fact that B1 was branched off of A is a problem, potentially it could be rebased onto master first.

At the end of the day, the answer to this depends on what your development process looks like, and how you use branches in your development process.

Comment: how can i update B1 after B2 is merged into master? will merging the updated master into B1 be safe? also, can you describe more concretely how development process affects merging? e.g. in which scenario would B1 branched off A be a problem?

Comment: in effect what i want to ask is when does it make sense to merge back in order and when does it make sense to merge directly whether it be feature branches backwards towards master or master towards feature branches or between offshoots of feature branches?

Comment: The development process _we_ use, developers make branches for the task they're working on, and it's expected that they might rebase and squash some commits before merging back to master. In that case you don't want another developer to have branched off of one of those branches.

Comment: assuming we don't rebase or squash within A, B1, and B2, will it be safe to merge B2 in master and then update B1 from master?

Comment: I think it almost never matters what order you merge back

Comment: Yes, that will be safe. All a merge does is introduce a commit with two parents

Answer (score 1):

(This should logically be a comment, but I need to format it, which I cannot do in a comment.  Plus, of course, it's far too long. :-) )

In [SpoonMeiser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53008110/1256452) (correct and upvoted) we have this drawing:

```
B1                ,-o--o--o
                 /
A             ,-o--o
             /      \         
B2          /        '-o--o
           /               \
master  --o--o--o-----------o--
```

I feel the need to point out that this drawing is a bit misleading: it makes people think that the bottom row commits are the commits that are reachable from `master`, that the next row up are the commits reachable from `B2`, that the third row are commits reachable from `A`, and the top row are the commits reachable from `B1`.

I've used this odd phrase, *reachable from*, instead of the more obvious word, *on*.  Why are we calling commits *reachable* instead of just saying which branch they're on?

The answer is that commits are often on **many branches at the same time**.  Let's give each of these commits a one-letter name (starting from `C` to avoid `A` and `B`), and move the branch names to my favorite position, at the *right*, like so:

```
             ,-E--F--G   <-- B1
            /
         ,-D--H   <-------- A
        /      \
       /        '-I--J   <-- B2
      /               \
...--C--K--L-----------M   <-- master
```

The way Git deals with these commits is to start at the commit to which each individual name points: for `master`, that's commit `M`, while it's commit `H` for branch A.  Starting from this end commit—such as `J` for branch B2—Git then works *backwards*: `J` leads back to `I`, then to `H` and `D` and `C` and so on.  So branch B2 contains *all of these commits*.  Meanwhile branch `master` starts at `M`, which leads back to both `J` and `L`.  So `master` contains every commit that `B2` currently contains, plus commits `L` and `K` as well.

The strategy one should use for `git merge` depends on what result one wants to obtain in the future.  That is, we must plan now for what we'll do tomorrow, or next week, or next year.

What `git checkout` does is to extract the commit to which the branch name points.  For instance, if we `git checkout` branch B1, we get commit `G`.  The snapshot stored in `G` goes into our *index* (from which we'll make the next commit, when we get to that point) and into our *work-tree* (where we can actually see and work on the files).  If we made a new commit, that would get a new hash ID—we'll use the next letter after `M` here, or `N`, and draw it:

```
             ,-E--F--G--N   <-- B1 (HEAD)
            /
         ,-D--H   <-------- A
        /      \
       /        '-I--J   <-- B2
      /               \
...--C--K--L-----------M   <-- master
```

Note that the `git commit` updated the current branch—which Git knows because `git checkout` attached `HEAD` to the branch name—so that it now points to the new commit just made.  The new commit points back to the commit we `git checkout`-ed, i.e., the one that *was* current until we made the new one.

What `git merge` does is to find the *merge base* between the current commit—now `N`—and the commit we name.  If we say `git merge A`, the name `A` translates to commit `H`, so Git finds commit `H` in the graph, and finds commit `N` in the graph, and then works backwards through this graph to find the best *common* commit—the best commit that's on *both* branches.  "Best", loosely translated, means "closest to the two ends", so here it is commit `D`.

The merge action—the verb part of *to merge*—combines commits `N` and `H` with respect to `D` by doing, in effect, two `git diff` commands:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-N>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-H>   # what they changed
```

Git figures out which files we changed, and what we did to them.  Then it figures out what files they changed, and what they did.  Then it simply (hah) *combines* the two sets of changes.  These combined changes are applied to the snapshot in the base, here `D`, to come up with the new snapshot.

Having combined the changes successfully—at least, as long as *Git* thinks it succeeded in combining them—Git will go on to make a *merge commit* that, like `M`, has two parents.  The first parent will be commit `N`, and the second parent will be commit `H`, the one we chose to merge.  The result is added to the `HEAD` branch as usual, so we get:

```
             ,-E--F--G--N--O   <-- B1 (HEAD)
            /  ,----------'
         ,-D--H   <-------- A
        /      \
       /        '-I--J   <-- B2
      /               \
...--C--K--L-----------M   <-- master
```

If we were now to ask Git to merge B1 and B2, Git would walk this graph to find the best "common starting point".  Without commit `O`, that common starting point is commit `D`, but with `O`, the common starting point is `H`.

In all cases, these "normal" Git commands simply *add to* the graph.  Each new commit has one parent if it's a regular commit, or two if it is a merge commit.  The additions reshape the graph, with merges changing which commit a *future* merge will choose as its merge base.  So the merges we make now are the ones we need to do something now, but they are also the ones we do now to make the merges we might do later, easier.

There are some Git commands that can *remove* commits, by forcing a branch name to point to a different (old) place in the graph, instead of adding new commits to the graph.  The `git reset` command is particularly good at this, but `git rebase` also does it: first, it copies a bunch of commits to "new and improved" ones, then it moves the branch name to point to the last of the copies just made.  Removed commits do not, in general, actually go away immediately: Git tries to give you a month or more to change your mind and bring them back.  But they do become harder to find, because the way Git normally *finds* commits is to start from a branch name (or a tag name) and look at the one commit that this name finds, and then use that commit to work backwards through the graph.

Comment: awesome answer. I learned quite a bit. One question, excluding destructive actions like rebase, squash and reset which remove commits, is there any way merge order can mess up diffs or final commit content or anything else? are merges commutative and associative?

Comment: I understand conflict resolution decisions can flow through merges and order can matter there. Would there be any other reason to merge in order or e.g. if I have branches `master->X->Y->Z` can I  merge an updated master again into Z first instead of through `X->Y->Z` and update Y and X later on?

Comment: @ChaudhryJunaid: The default combining process is commutative. `-X` with `ours` or `theirs` says to use the left ("ours") or right ("theirs") side in case of conflicts; this obviously is *not* commutative. :-) When the *to merge* (verb) process is followed by creating of *a merge* (noun), a merge commit with two parents, the *first* parent is the left side / `--ours` commit, so this also is not commutative; and the current branch name, which selects the left side / ours commit, is the branch name that is updated. So these are all the asymmetric parts.

Comment: As you note, the resolution flows through, so when merging commit Y and then Z, or Z and then Y, the order can matter there (violating associativity). If there are no conflicts, the order does not matter (the merge meets associativity requirement).  It's also worth pointing out that Git offers an *octopus merge* strategy: `git merge Y Z` merges HEAD/X with commits Y and Z simultaneously. This strategy refuses to operate if there are conflicts.